# How can we add power-bi report inside fabric - JS Canvas

Tags: angular, canvas, iframe, powerbi, fabricjs

How can we add an Power-bi report inside a fabric js canvas ? is it possible to add an interactive iframe inside fabric js canvas.

I am expecting to have an PowerBI report to be integrated inside fabric JS canvas.aso if it's possible to add iframe inside fabric JS canvas.